# What transfers energy

Tags: energy, particle-physics, momentum

Suppose a moving object collides with another resting object. First object gives momentum hence mechanical energy to the second object. It shouldn't be like energy suddenly appears on the second object. There should be some way that the second object gains energy from the first object.  In theoretical physics, are there some kind of weightless carriers those can convey the energy from one object to another? What's the real nature of energy transfer?

Comment: It is an interesting question....but then again, what would you say is the mechanism of energy transfewr when apple falls to the ground?

Comment: How deep of an answer are you looking for here?

Comment: @ Aaron. Thanks for the response. I am a biologist. I would like to know deeply but without any mathematical approach.

Comment: @ Zarko. Well classically its the transformation of energy trapped withing the same object right. The potential energy is converted to the kinetic energy. This happens withing the same object. But what about the scenario when one object gains energy from another? who is responsible for transforming?

Comment: Suppose there is some kind of carrier for energy transfer. Then what would transfer energy to the carrier?

Comment: @ Stephane. I might be wrong, but I believe that carriers are originated withing the object being transferring energy. But if we think more deeply, deeply and further deeply to the finest point, I assume we cannot answer that question, because the theoretical physics has not found the answer yet!

Answer (score 4):

Forces are transmitted between colliding objects like rubber balls by means of the electrostatic repulsion of the electron clouds that surround the atoms which make up those objects; in addition, those electron clouds strongly resist being forced to overlap because of quantum-mechanical effects. They therefore push back against being pushed together.

In the specific case of colliding rubber balls, when the balls begin to touch, the rubber molecules respond by deforming. This deformation process involves displacements of the electron clouds surrounding those molecules, which causes the kinks in the molecule's shape to slightly bend. Energy is stored in those deformations as the balls impact each other and is then released as the balls rebound.

Comment: What if I ask for a deeper answer? What transfers energy between electron clouds? (same question different scale)

Comment: @ niels. Thanks for the answer. I ended up with another question. How the communication happens between two electron clouds. How does one cloud send the information to the other one to cause deformation? I feel that there is something that I don't know. Answer would be appreciated.

Comment: the model of force communication between charged objects like electrons is that photons shuttle back and forth between the objects to transfer forces.  for this reason, photons are called the *mediators* of the electromagnetic force.

Comment: @ Neils. Okay got it. That's what I wanted to know. Do they somehow interact with the electric field? How do the know that the communication happens between two given objects but not with nearby objects?